# Django .defer() for removing value from queryset

Tags: python, django, search, django-views

```
def get_client_queryset(query=None):
    queryset = []
    queries = query.split(' ')
    for q in queries:
        details = clients.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=q) |
            Q(number__icontains=q) |
            Q(email__icontains=q)
        ).distinct().defer(unique_num)
        for client in details:
            queryset.append(client)
    return list(set(queryset))
```

the .defer('unique_num') is still being returned and displayed in the queryset. The provided function is a search function

Comment: That makes sense, since `.defer(...)` means that you will *later* lazy load that field if necessary.

Comment: In other words, with `.defer()` one states "I will (likely) not need that field", but if I need it, make a query to fetch it.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do. Likey there is a better solution than to make a query per `queries` item.

Comment: I want to return all other fields except 'unique_num' and 'primary_key'

Comment: then you can use `.values()` and list all the items to return, but I don't see why `unique_num` and `primary_key` should not be returned. You can create a serializer that omits these fields. Often it is better to return model objects, and let such serializer handle how to convert it to JSON/...

Answer (score 0):

> the `.defer('unique_num')` is still being returned and displayed in the queryset.

That makes sense, since [**`.defer(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer) means you will *lazy load* that column. Therefore `.defer(…)` is often used to prevent loading a column with large amounts of data.

One can make use of [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) to return dictionaries which contain only the values listed above.

```
from re import escape as rescape

def get_client_queryset(query=None):
    regex = '|'.join(rescape(q) for q in query.split(' '))
    return clients.objects.filter(
        Q(name__iregex=regex) |
        Q(number__iregex=regex) |
        Q(email__iregex=regex)
    ).values('name', 'number', 'email')
```

It might however be a better idea to return the model objects, and then serialize this to a JSON blob (or another output format) with a [*Serializer* [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#using-modelserializers): Django's REST framework is made to create REST APIs. One can define such API for search results, and decide what data to pass to the client. In that case the queryset returns the `'unique_num'`, but is not serialized:

```
from re import escape as rescape
from rest_framework import serializers

class ClientSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        exclude = ['unique_num']

def get_client_queryset(query=None):
    regex = '|'.join(rescape(q) for q in query.split(' '))
    return clients.objects.filter(
        Q(name__iregex=regex) |
        Q(number__iregex=regex) |
        Q(email__iregex=regex)
    )
```

then the view thus looks like:

```
serializer = ClientSerializer(get_client_queryset(), many=True)
data = serializer.data
```